# HTML Fomat selection disappeared with V1.30

Tags: javascript, html, visual-studio-code, autoformat

On VS Code HTML or JavaScript if I select a block of code and by clicking on right button on the options available I could "Format Selection" which indents ar auto-format the selection.

After updating to V1.30 this option has disappeared from right click context menu.

Do you know why? How can I enable again?

Thanks

Comment: Click "Command Palette" and then type "Format Selection"

Comment: if I right click and select Command Palette and type format I get "There is no selection formatter for 'html' -files installed". But HTML formatted is enabled.

Comment: Thanks for answering anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Go to File -> Preferences -> Settings and then type in format in the search bar at the top of that page, and check the settings in there, there are a lot of ways to format the code, so you may find some new stuff there that will be beneficial as well as which setting you have turned off. I just upgraded and have the format functionality still in my instance.

Comment: Thanks, for answering. I see HTML Formatter is enabled. Rolling back to V1.29.1 I have formatter back. But installing a fresh V1.30 on another PC I get the same problem. Format Selection option has disappeared. Also getting "There is no selection formatter for 'html' -files installed" when accessing from Command palette.

Answer (score 0):

You can shorten this sequence you're following by just enabling autoformat. Just go to your VS settings and search for autoformat and enable it for the required languages. It might ask you to install extensions for linting depending on the language.